# Crystal Reports: multiple columns by group

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns

I am working on a report that and by using Format with multiple columns and Format groups with multiple columns, the report displays data like this.

```
station 1    Station 4
Mike         Barry
Sam          Jim
Abe          Gary

Station 2
Ruth
Ben
Karim

Station 3
Cat
Billy
Erin
```

And so on. The report is grouped by the station and I want the report to display data like this.

```
Station 1   Station 2    Station 3    Station 4
Mike        Ruth         Cat          Barry
sam         Ben          Billy        Jim
Abe         Karim        Erin         Gary
```

I looked through the search information but did not find a way for me to list the group and the data side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Open the section expert, layout, print direction, set "Across then Down".

Adjust the width of the section to fit 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to insert a group footer (not suppress it), and have it set to "print at bottom of page."